# Charge CIM Profile without storing address in the profile

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I would like to store the customer's address book on my servers, and a tokenized version of their credit card. Then I would like the ability to charge the customer profile with the address I provide from my servers. Is this possible?

My concern is that if I store the customer's addresses on the Authorize.net servers it will be a slow checkout process for my customers because at the time of checkout I have to retrieve all of the addresses from authorize.net. Similarly, the "My Account-Addresses" section would be slow. Also I might store special fields for the customer as part of their address so it makes the data storage simpler.

Is this possible? I have mostly seen examples of the authorize.net CIM api being used to store ALL of the customer information (Billing, shipping addresses). Also the API seems to be written this way as well to promote this type of behavior.

Thank you,

Comment: What you want to do is exactly what CIM does

Comment: Well I e-mailed Authorize.net and they said you cannot charge without a billing address being associated to a customer profile. Is there any way around this? "The Billing Address must be stored as a part of the customer profile if you want it to be a part of the transaction, but the shipping address can be submitted at the time the transaction is processed. Our sample XML for charging a customer profile actually gives an example of submitting a payment profile ID alongside a shipping address."

Answer (score 0):

From your question's heading, it seems you want to charge a CIM profile which doesn't contains customer address.

And It seems Authorize.Net allows you to create a customer payment profile only with payment data and without customer address (as the address is optional).

And later on you can charge a customer profile via this [createTransactionRequest](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile)